# Hi! my Ads in Admob don`t show hoover the default this show

Tags: flutter

my Ads in Admob don`t show hoover the default this show

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device SM G935F...
E/BufferQueueProducer( 4627): [unnamed-4627-20] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer( 4627): [unnamed-4627-21] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
Restarted application in ٢٬٥٤٤ms.
D/DynamitePackage( 4627): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads     ( 4627): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("AEF498473884A9F0F52D51F982E7E4C1")) to get test ads on this device.
I/Ads     ( 4627): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("AEF498473884A9F0F52D51F982E7E4C1")) to get test ads on this device.
W/Ads     ( 4627): Not retrying to fetch app settings
W/cr_AwContents( 4627): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
I/cr_Ime  ( 4627): ImeThread is not enabled.
W/cr_BindingManager( 4627): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4627
D/DynamitePackage( 4627): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads     ( 4627): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("AEF498473884A9F0F52D51F982E7E4C1")) to get test ads on this device.
W/Ads     ( 4627): Not retrying to fetch app settings
E/EGL_adreno( 4627): tid 4719: eglSurfaceAttrib(1492): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer( 4627): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x95fddfa0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 4627): Init ExoPlayerLib/2.4.2 [SM-G935F, SM-G935F, samsung, 22]
E/EGL_adreno( 4627): tid 4719: eglSurfaceAttrib(1492): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer( 4627): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x95fddfa0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/Ads     ( 4627): Ad failed to load : 3
W/cr_AwContents( 4627): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
I/cr_Ime  ( 4627): ImeThread is not enabled.
W/cr_BindingManager( 4627): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4627
I/DynamiteModule( 4627): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:210890500
I/DynamiteModule( 4627): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 210890500
W/WebView ( 4627): java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'FinalizerDaemon'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {3b03de9b} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {3b03de9b})
W/WebView ( 4627):  at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2203)
W/WebView ( 4627):  at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:857)
W/WebView ( 4627):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.aV(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@210890500@210890500000.359169010.359169010:1)
W/WebView ( 4627):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.destroy(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@210890500@210890500000.359169010.359169010:8)
W/WebView ( 4627):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.y.destroy(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@210890500@210890500000.359169010.359169010:5)
```

```dart
  import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:admob_flutter/admob_flutter.dart';
    // import 'package:admob_flutter_example/extensions.dart';
    
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      // Initialize without device test ids
      Admob.initialize();
    
      // Add a list of test ids.
      // Admob.initialize(testDeviceIds: ['YOUR DEVICE ID']);
    
      runApp(MyMaterialApp());
    }
    
    class MyMaterialApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyMaterialAppState createState() => _MyMaterialAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyMaterialAppState extends State<MyMaterialApp> {
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = GlobalKey();
      AdmobBannerSize bannerSize;
      AdmobInterstitial interstitialAd;
      AdmobReward rewardAd;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        // You should execute `Admob.requestTrackingAuthorization()` here before showing any ad.
    
        bannerSize = AdmobBannerSize.BANNER;
    
        interstitialAd = AdmobInterstitial(
          adUnitId: getInterstitialAdUnitId(),
          listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
            if (event == AdmobAdEvent.closed) interstitialAd.load();
            handleEvent(event, args, 'Interstitial');
          },
        );
    
        rewardAd = AdmobReward(
          adUnitId: getRewardBasedVideoAdUnitId(),
          listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
            if (event == AdmobAdEvent.closed) rewardAd.load();
            handleEvent(event, args, 'Reward');
          },
        );
    
        interstitialAd.load();
        rewardAd.load();
      }
    
      void handleEvent(
          AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args, String adType) {
        switch (event) {
          case AdmobAdEvent.loaded:
            showSnackBar('New Admob $adType Ad loaded!');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.opened:
            showSnackBar('Admob $adType Ad opened!');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.closed:
            showSnackBar('Admob $adType Ad closed!');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad:
            showSnackBar('Admob $adType failed to load. :(');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.rewarded:
            showDialog(
              context: scaffoldState.currentContext,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return WillPopScope(
                  child: AlertDialog(
                    content: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Reward callback fired. Thanks Andrew!'),
                        Text('Type: ${args['type']}'),
                        Text('Amount: ${args['amount']}'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onWillPop: () async {
                    scaffoldState.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
                    return true;
                  },
                );
              },
            );
            break;
          default:
        }
      }
    
      void showSnackBar(String content) {
        scaffoldState.currentState.showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(content),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
          ),
          home: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
              key: scaffoldState,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('AdmobFlutter'),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          fullscreenDialog: true,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
    
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'FullscreenDialog',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ), // .withBottomAdmobBanner(context),
              bottomNavigationBar: Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 60,
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: FlatButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Show Interstitial',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if (await interstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                                    interstitialAd.show();
                                  } else {
                                    showSnackBar(
                                        'Interstitial ad is still loading...');
                                  }
                                },
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: FlatButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Show Reward',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if (await rewardAd.isLoaded) {
                                    rewardAd.show();
                                  } else {
                                    showSnackBar('Reward ad is still loading...');
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: PopupMenuButton(
                                initialValue: bannerSize,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Banner size',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                offset: Offset(0, 20),
                                onSelected: (AdmobBannerSize newSize) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    bannerSize = newSize;
                                  });
                                },
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                <PopupMenuEntry<AdmobBannerSize>>[
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    value: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
                                    child: Text('BANNER'),
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    value: AdmobBannerSize.LARGE_BANNER,
                                    child: Text('LARGE_BANNER'),
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    value: AdmobBannerSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE,
                                    child: Text('MEDIUM_RECTANGLE'),
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    value: AdmobBannerSize.FULL_BANNER,
                                    child: Text('FULL_BANNER'),
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    value: AdmobBannerSize.LEADERBOARD,
                                    child: Text('LEADERBOARD'),
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    value: AdmobBannerSize.SMART_BANNER(context),
                                    child: Text('SMART_BANNER'),
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    value: AdmobBannerSize.ADAPTIVE_BANNER(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                          .size
                                          .width
                                          .toInt() -
                                          40, // considering EdgeInsets.all(20.0)
                                    ),
                                    child: Text('ADAPTIVE_BANNER'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: FlatButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Push Page',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        }),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Scrollbar(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        itemCount: 1000,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          if (index != 0 && index % 6 == 0) {
                            return Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                                  child: AdmobBanner(
                                    adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
                                    adSize: bannerSize,
                                    listener: (AdmobAdEvent event,
                                        Map<String, dynamic> args) {
                                      handleEvent(event, args, 'Banner');
                                    },
                                    onBannerCreated:
                                        (AdmobBannerController controller) {
                                      // Dispose is called automatically for you when Flutter removes the banner from the widget tree.
                                      // Normally you don't need to worry about disposing this yourself, it's handled.
                                      // If you need direct access to dispose, this is your guy!
                                      // controller.dispose();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 100.0,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                                  color: Colors.cyan,
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          }
                          return Container(
                            height: 100.0,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                            color: Colors.cyan,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Another option is to fix a banner ad to the top or bottom of your content.
                  // Notice that banners are not scrolling, which is a violation of admob policy.
                  //
                  // See: https://github.com/kmcgill88/admob_flutter/issues/194
                  // "banner ads should not move as a user scrolls, as users may try to
                  // click on the menu but end up clicking on the ad accidentally instead.
                  // This specific implementation is against policy and we reserve the right
                  // to disable ad serving to your app."
    
                  // Builder(
                  //   builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  //     final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
                  //     final height = max(size.height * .05, 50.0);
                  //     return Container(
                  //       width: size.width,
                  //       height: height,
                  //       child: AdmobBanner(
                  //         adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
                  //         adSize: AdmobBannerSize.ADAPTIVE_BANNER(
                  //           width: size.width.toInt(),
                  //         ),
                  //         listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
                  //           handleEvent(event, args, 'Banner');
                  //         },
                  //       ),
                  //     );
                  //   },
                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
        // .withBottomAdmobBanner(context);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        interstitialAd.dispose();
        rewardAd.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    }
    
    /*
    Test Id's from:
    https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner
    https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner
    
    App Id - See README where these Id's go
    Android: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
    iOS: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511
    
    Banner
    Android: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
    iOS: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716
    
    Interstitial
    Android: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
    iOS: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910
    
    Reward Video
    Android: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
    iOS: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313
    */
    
    String getBannerAdUnitId() {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';
      } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        return 'ca-app-pub-5721905078810865/2810642114';
      }
      return null;
    }
    
    String getInterstitialAdUnitId() {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910';
      } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
      }
      return null;
    }
    
    String getRewardBasedVideoAdUnitId() {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313';
      } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917';
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ads take some time to be configured to your app
last time I use Ads takes like 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

From your logs I see `I/Ads( 4627): Ad failed to load : 3`

The Error code is 3, and it stands for the ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory. It could be that your admob account is new or it may be under review. I recommend that you use a test device or use the admob test id during development. And for further troubleshooting check your admob account for any policy violation.

**Advice**

Make sure you don't run production ads during development or testing, it is against the admob policies and could lead to an ad limit warning(where you app would be able to fetch ads). Try to always test with Admob Test Ads.

Your implementation seems okay! But I recommend you use [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) the package made by Google. It will be more reliable.